# Home Realm not being passed to logon.microsoft.com

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-active-directory

I am using the code below to try and pass on the home realm to windows azure active directory sign on. I can see that the code is adding the whr parameter to login.windows.net but it doesn't make it to logon.microsoftonline.com. I'm trying to get it to sign in automatically for users who are on the domain.

```
     private void WSFederationAuthenticationModule_RedirectingToIdentityProvider(object sender, RedirectingToIdentityProviderEventArgs e)     
    {

        if (Request.QueryString.AllKeys.Any(k => k == "whr"))
        {
            e.SignInRequestMessage.HomeRealm = Request["whr"];                
        }
    }
```